# How to solve some algebraic expressions and find the GCD of a number and one obtained from evaluating the algebra in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, algebra, greatest-common-divisor

I'm writing a java program that will find the GCD (greatest common divisor) of a number N. The program should evaluate some algebraic expression. lemme explain it further;
1.  Calculate √(N) 
2.  Divide the result of (1) above by 18.
3.  Compute the ceiling function of step(2) above and call it f. In other words, f = ceiling function of [√(N) divided by 18].
4.  Set up the following three algebraic expressions in x  and execute them sequentially from (a) to (c):

a) H1(x) = (N -1-18x ),  x will take values from zero to f. 
For each x, compute the gcd of H1(x) and N. Let’s call this gcd, d. 
That is, d= gcd (N, H1(x)) or ( N, H1(x)).
If d =1, increase x by 1 and continue to do so until d > 1 or you come to x = f.
If d > 1, you have found one nontrivial divisor of N. Call it q.  The other divisor of N is the value of H1(x) divided by q plus 1. Let’s call it p. Therefore, p = (  +1). 
Then state that the divisors of N are p and q. Then prompt for another N to be entered or ask if the user wants to enter another N to be tested- with a Y/N option.

But if you could not find a gcd > 1 for H1(x) between x = 0 and x = f, move to (b) below:

b) H2(x) = (N -11-18x ), x will range from zero to f. 
For each x, compute the gcd of H2(x) and N. Let’s call this gcd, d. That is, 
d= gcd(N, H2(x)) or ( N, H2(x)).
If d =1, increase x by 1 and continue to do so until d > 1 or you come to x = f.

If d > 1, you have found one nontrivial divisor of N. Call it q.  The other divisor of N is the value of H2(x) divided by q. Let’s call it p.

Therefore, p = (  +1). 
Then state that the divisors of N are p and q. Then prompt for another N to be entered or ask if the user wants to enter another N to be tested- with a Y/N option.

But if you could not find a  gcd > 1 for H2(x) between x = 0 and x = f, move to (c) below:

c) H4(x) = (N -13-18x ), x will range from zero to f. 
For each x, compute the gcd of H4(x) and N. Let’s call this gcd, d. 
If d =1, increase x by 1 and continue to do so until d > 1 or you come to x = f.
If d > 1, you have found one nontrivial divisor of N. Call it q.  The other divisor of N is the value of H4(x) divided by q. Let’s call it p.

Therefore, p = (  +1).

Then state that the divisors of N are p and q.

See what I've done so far;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num;
    double sqrtnum;
    double dividedsqrtnum;
    double f;
    int x = 0;
    float a;
    int d;
    float p;
    int q;

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the number 'N'");
     num = input.nextInt();

     if( (num % 3) != 0){

         System.out.println( "The number you entered is a semi-prime");

         sqrtnum = Math.sqrt(num);

         dividedsqrtnum = sqrtnum / 18;

         f = Math.ceil(dividedsqrtnum) ;

         System.out.println("The value of f is " + f);

         // Algebraic expressions

         for (x=0; x <= f; x++){

             while (d == 1 || x ==f){

         a = (num - 1 - 18 * x);
    d = findGCD(num,a);
        if ( d == 1){

        x = x++;
        }

        else{
            q = d;
            p = (a / q + 1);

            System.out.println("The divisors of "+ num +" are "+ p +" and " + q +" do you want to test another number? Y or N " );
            }

                    }
                                }
                            }

     else{
         System.out.println("The number is not a semi-prime");

     }
```

}

```
 private static int findGCD(float num,float a) {
        //base case

        return findGCD(a, num%a);
    }

}
```

Help me guys, I'm really stuck.

Comment: (+Close for now) stuck with what and where ? your question is really hard to read Try to make specific question not just copy some assignment algorithm and code without explaining what exactly is wrong Add test examples +what have you tried so far etc... Right now there is all bunch of thing that you are (not) asking each of can be as separate question ,,,  I would start with GCD what approach you want to use what are the constrains (max number of numbers, max value of numbers,runtime or memory limits)?

Comment: Your "question" starts: *I'm writing a java program that will find the GCD (greatest common divisor) of a number N*. This doesn't make any sense, because to compute the GCD you need two numbers, not just one. Please revise your question.